# Swift Struct: adding new parameters at runtime

Tags: swift, struct, runtime

Given an instance of struct like this:

```
struct Size {
    var width: Int
    var height: Int
}
```

Is there the possibility to extend it by runtime to:

```
struct Size {
    var width: Int
    var height: Int
    var depth: Int
}
```

adding a new parameter to the existing instance of Size struct ?

Thanks

Comment: that is not instance, that is simply struct,  adding properties to the struct, rather that parameters to instance.

Comment: Maybe `[String: Int]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Swift. You should know about properites of your object when you're creating it.

You have to options:

- Make `depth` property optional. Then this property doesn't have to have any value

  ```
  var depth: Int?
  ```
- Or give it default value

  ```
  var depth: Int = 1
  ```

  With this second option you can create custom `init` with default value

  ```
  struct Size {
      var width, height, depth: Int
  }

  extension Size {
      init(width: Int, height: Int) {
          self.init(width: width, height: height, depth: 1)
      }
  }

  Size(width: 1, height: 1)
  Size(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
  ```

Comment: Is there any posibility using computed properties in the extension ? That's in case "depth" was added only at runtime ?

Comment: @GiuseppeRobertoRossi if you don't know if there is some `depth`, you have to make it optional. This means that all computed properties connected with `depth` should also return optional. Since if you don't know if you have depth, you also don't know if math with this property returns something.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way adding that but what you can do is the following, You can declare everything that you might need at run time as an optional, plus 
if however you were able to add new properties to the `struct` at run time what is the use of it ? how are you going to use them ?.

Simply optional the values.

```
struct Size {
 var width: Int
 var height: Int
 var depth: Int? // this could be nil or Int 
}
```